# Bash нужно прописать пароль в скрипте

Tags: bash

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo -u postgres  psql -d testbd -c "select * from test_table"
```

Как можно написать пароль, чтобы при автоматическом запуске не спрашивал.

Comment: вместо прописывания пароля открытым текстом, можно в sudoers желаемую команду прописать: [how to run script as another user without password](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6905697/4279)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавить опцию *-ppassword*:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo -u postgres -ppassword  psql -d testbd -c "select * from test_table"
```